# Identify IC AMGJ 458 (Buck ?)

Tags: identification

It gets 20 V at the input and puts out 5 V.

Probably a buck converter with feedback circuitry on the left.

Anyone an idea what IC that is?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MP9943GQ -? With a search of +"amgj 458" on Ecosia.org using the search term I found only one result, in russian. (https://rcopen.com/forum/f90/topic247581/1420)

Comment: I wonder why I could not find it :/ thanks!

Comment: No problem. Used Ecosia.org w/ search term +"amgj 458"